# Issue deleting row from SQL Table

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to remove a row from an SQL table using this code below. However, whenever I call this method I get this following error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Plumber (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM service WHERE name = Plumber

```
public boolean deleteService(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    boolean result = false;
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "
            + TABLE_SERVICE
            + " WHERE "
            + COLUMN_NAME
            + " = \""
            + name
            + "\""
            ;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String nameStr = cursor.getString(0);
        db.delete(TABLE_SERVICE, COLUMN_NAME + " = " + nameStr, null);
        cursor.close();
        result = true;
    }
    db.close();
    return result;
}
```

This is my table

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

    String CREATE_USERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_SERVICE + "("
            +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_RATE + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY + " TEXT," + COLUMN_SUBCATEGORY + " TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS_TABLE);

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should add the structure of your table.

Comment: the error says there is no column "name" in the table "service" ... so is there such a column in the database you're connected to in the code?

Comment: What is the actual name of the column `COLUMN_NAME `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you're fetching all the rows that in `COLUMN_NAME` have the value `name`.  
Next you want to delete the 1st of these rows (maybe it's the only one?) because `nameStr` gets the value of the 1st column which is `COLUMN_NAME`. 
Why are you doing this? 
Just execute this statement:

```
int number = db.delete(TABLE_SERVICE, COLUMN_NAME + " = '" + name + "'", null);
```

if `number` gets the value `0` then no rows were deleted, else it gets the number of deleted rows.

Answer (score 0):

`delete` deletes *rows* not columns.

If you want to get rid of a column, you need to drop it.  The SQL syntax is:

```
alter table table_service drop column <column_name>;
```

I don't know how to express this in java with the methods that you are using.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say delete row, thats what I'm trying to do but it isn't working

Comment: And please don't generate sql by string concatenation. Use parameter queries to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your SQL syntax is correct, and that "Plumber" is a string with double quotes. By my experience, these errors are usually caused by an incorrect column or name.

Use this format:

`DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition(s)`

[SQLite browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org) can also help you visualize your database.